# Trying to get to last cursor position with "moveToLast" sqlite DB is causing force close

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I can open my Database with no apparent problem,

this piece of code works perfectly....

```
if (main.cursor.isLast()) {
            main.cursor.moveToFirst();

        } else {

            main.cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

but if I try to go the other way with the following code, down my database it force closes...

```
try {
            if ((main.cursor.isFirst()) || (main.cursor.isBeforeFirst())) {
                main.cursor.moveToPosition((main.cursor.getCount()) - 1);
                main.cursor.moveToPosition(lastrow);
            } else {

                main.cursor.moveToPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've looked all over stackoverflow and online trying to figure this out...

please help!

Edit: Logcat

```
10-11 14:57:07.722: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(450): Shutting down VM
10-11 14:57:07.722: WARN/dalvikvm(450): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x40015560)
10-11 14:57:07.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 14:57:07.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 185 requested, with a size of 185
10-11 14:57:07.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
10-11 14:57:07.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
10-11 14:57:07.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(450):     at     android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
```

Comment: When your app is force closed, check logcat to see details on what the problem really is.

Comment: Also, if you want to traverse your query backwards, I would recommend reversing the order of the data in the query instead of reading from back to front.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat show an error: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 185 requested, with a size of 185, that mean you move to wrong position. 
Seem that this line cause :

```
main.cursor.moveToPosition(lastrow);
```

I think that line is useless.